# Cant send logs to Stackdrvier using latest version of google.cloud.logging.log4net from GCE instance

Tags: log4net, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-logging

I referred the [sample application](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dotnet-docs-samples/tree/master/logging/api/Log4Net) to send logs using `Log4net`.
The version of `Nuget` package used in the app is `1.0.0-beta05`.

When I update the `Nuget` package to the latest version(or any other stable version), I'm not able to send logs.

Are there any changes that need to be done in the code for using the latest version of library?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest going through [this document](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/how-to-enable-google-stackdriver-logging-monitoring-and-error-reporting-for-net-apps?hl=am) on How to enable Google Stackdriver Logging, Monitoring and Error Reporting for .NET apps. It further points to ["How-To" documentation](https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/docs/setup/compute-engine#samples) for installing and using the Stackdriver Diagnostics ASP.NET NuGet package for .NET applications, where Usage suggets adding a statement to your application code. Have you tried all that already?